# Возможно ли обойти все страницы сайта с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, парсер

Хочу обойти все страницы сайта auto.ru, но почему-то после первой страницы скрипт перестает работать. Как решить проблему?

```
var p=1
function main() {
    if (p<4){   // для начала пробую первые 4
    url = "https://auto.ru/moskva/motorcycle/all/?beaten=1&custom_state_key=CLEARED&geo_id=213&geo_radius=200&image=true&sort_offers=cr_date-DESC&top_days=off&currency=RUR&output_type=list&page_num_offers="+p;
    parse(); //вывод описания объявления
    document.location.href = url;
    p=p+1
    }
}   
//main()

var timerId = setInterval(main(), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

при вызове location.href = ... вы покидаете страницу, а ваш скрипт - её часть. Он уничтожается вместе со всем остальным. Чтоб сделать то, что вы хотите, открываейте страницы внутри фрейма, а управляющий скрипт должен работать снаружи

Comment: Не совсем понял, то есть нужно разделить обход страниц и парсинг, а как в этом случае использовать setInterval?

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков Сделай страницу, на которой будет твой скрипт где setInterval и iframe. А ту часть, где парсер, надо инжектить внутрь фрейма каждый раз, когда ты открываешь следующую страницу и целевого сайта

Comment: Если честно, второй раз в жизни имею дело с javasript, а с парсингом вообще первый раз. Может быть у вас есть какой-то пример реализации такого обхода или вы знаете, где он может быть?

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков Я когда-то делал парсер в виде расширения для хрома - https://github.com/aka-darth/myscore_parser_chrome_extension